# Libgdx Bitmap Font white box

Tags: text, libgdx

It seems to be rendering but just becoming a white box. There are no errors. Thanks in advance.

https://gyazo.com/e7c238be0cbb302643eb84de710aebcd

```
  colture = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/fontcoture.fnt"),false);
```

---

```
game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
game.batch.begin();
game.batch.draw(ball, player.b2Body.getPosition().x - MarioBros.RADIUS_CHARACTER / MarioBros.PPM, player.b2Body.getPosition().y - MarioBros.RADIUS_CHARACTER / MarioBros.PPM, 70 / MarioBros.PPM, 70 / MarioBros.PPM);
colture.setColor(256, 256, 256, 1);
colture.draw(game.batch,"Hello m8", 10 / MarioBros.PPM,10 / MarioBros.PPM);
endOfGame();
game.batch.end();
```

Comment: I can't quite understand what your problem is but  `colture.setColor(256, 256, 256, 1);` those three "256" values make your font white. Try three "0" instead.

Comment: The white box just turns black @Enigo

Comment: oh, I get it, you use setColor method inside drawing. Try to set color only once after you create the "colture" object, e.g.
`colture = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/fontcoture.fnt"),false);
colture.setColor(256, 256, 256, 1);`

Comment: Thanks for you help. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use setColor method inside drawing. Try to set color only once after you create the "colture" object, e.g.

```
colture = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/fontcoture.fnt"),false);
colture.setColor(256, 256, 256, 1);
```